# Another Python question about any()/all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic, iterable

Let's say I have a list containing only True/False values in any order and the length of the list is not fixed. Let's call the list `myList`.

Then, there are three possibilities. The list only contains True values, the list only contains False values or the list contains a mix of True/False values in any order.

If I do:

```
if all(myList):
    print('All True')
elif any(myList):
    print('Mixed values')
else:
    print('All False')
```

I can know the general content of the list, all True, all False or mixed True/False values.

The question is: Is there a way to know if the list contains mixed True/False values without the `if elif else` test? Any built-in function to directly know I have mixed values in the list?

Comment: can you share the source data please? Are we looking at a list of lists or a dataframe?

Comment: It still isnt' clear what you mean by "it can be of any length" but in general it will be "[True, True] or [True, False] or [False, False]". IOW, you need to be able to describe the state you are interested in given a list of any length.

Comment: It is just a list of booleans.

Comment: @kbr85, how many booleans. Can it be `[True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, True]` ? If so, what's the result?

Comment: Having acquired enough reputation points, one thing that we should all focus is to write good questions that are less ambiguous. Please make the question clear enough that everyone can review and provide solution.

Comment: You need to better define the state you're looking for. Is it True followed by any number of Falses? Is it a list of Booleans with exactly one True? Exactly one False? An equal number of Trues and Falses? Your question is unanswerable as currently written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code basically iterates the list twice, but one time would be enough:

```
if 0 < sum(myList) < len(myList):
    print('Mixed values')
```

Comment: The list can have any number of elements. The length is not fixed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I realized that too, and edited the question. But thanks :)

Comment: @kbr85: You said it could only have 3 possible states, each of which has exactly 2 elements.

Comment: @kbr85 then what is the condition you are trying to evaluate, exactly?

Comment: This `if sum(listState) == 1` could also be a result of `[False,True]` but the requirement is `[True,False]`. So only `if listState == '[True, False]` would make sense.

Comment: @kbr85 then it *is completely ambigous* what you mean by "three states".

Comment: I edited the question. Considering your second suggestion I could do `a = sum(mylist) if a != len(myList) and a != 0: print('Mixed Values')` but I guess this is worst than the if elif else test.

Comment: @kbr85 I edited the answer as well. I think `sum` is still better and allows for shorted code

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: Is there a way to know if the list contains mixed True/False values without the if elif else test? Any built-in function to directly know I have mixed values in the list?

You can create a lambda to do this.

```
mixed = lambda x: len(set(x)) > 1
tf = [True, False, False, True]
f = [False, False, False]
t = [True, True, True]

mixed(tf) # returns true
mixed(t)  # returns false
mixed(f)  # returns false.
```

Note that the above will work for any list as it only checks for length of any set after duplicates have been removed.  But I would presume you don't let stray values enter into your list of booleans.

Comment: could also mean `[False, True]`

Comment: I know, I thought that is what the OP wanted.  I modified it to be more specific.

Comment: i know. I flagged it for closure until there is enough clarity on the question.